# Attempting to use MKLINK to link folders between two hard drives but keep getting an error

Tags: powershell, drive, mklink

So I'm currently running out of space on my C: Drive which I store windows on currently and I wish to create a link between my C: Drive and my E: Drive so that I can store Custom Content files without taking up more space on my C: Drive.

For those who don't know how The Sims custom content files work; Files are stored within the documents folder through the Electronic Arts game folder. Now, this Electronic Arts folder is stored on the C: Drive. So why don't I simply move the Electronic Arts folder? Because unfortunately, for whatever reason, if there is no Electronic Arts folder present in it's designated spot on your C: Drive, it automatically creates a new folder upon starting the game(No other way to fix this). Hence why I have resulted to this method. It has worked for multiple others but not for myself.

```
>> cmd /c mklink /C C:\Users\Eun\Documents\Electronic Arts\The Sims 4\Mods E:\The Sims 4\Sims 4 Mods\Mods
Invalid switch - "C".
```

This is currently what I have entered into Windows PowerShell and I've been running it through Administrator. I've moved all my files into the new folder on my E: Drive already and have left my C: folder empty. I have also checked all spelling and capital letters as I know this stuff can be very sensitive. 
So I'm *assuming* that my D: Folder is supposed to be my real_dir and my C: is my symlink_dir. Then again I could have misunderstood completely since I'm new to this and trying to read my way through it. If anyone is able to assist me with why the command is not working, I'll be very thankful.

Comment: Why do you use an additional `cmd /c` to run `mklink`? Powershell is - just like cmd - a command line interface. So you're starting a command line interface from another command line interface to start a command line tool?  ;-)

Comment: There is no `/C` parameter for `mklink`.  You want to use `/J` to create a junction or `/D` to create a directory symbolic link.  Also, you should put double quotes around your two paths.  @Olaf Though many times I see `cmd /c` used unnecessarily, in this case `mklink` is not its own executable but a command built into `Command Prompt`, so you have to use `cmd /c` here.

Comment: Thank you Bacon! Your solution worked! I also had to delete the premade sym folder I made as the command created a new one on its own!